# what is the correct syntax for awk's printf to insert multiple variables?

Tags: bash, awk, printf

I copied some code that was using printf to output how often strings appeared in files.

```
awk ' BEGIN {  print "The number of times a appears in the file:" ; }
/a/ {  a_counter+=1  ;  }
END {  printf "%s\n",  a_counter ; }
'  $file
```

After modifying the pattern to a variable, I wanted to include the pattern into the printf command, next to the count:

```
awk -v a="$GENE1" ' BEGIN {  print "The number of times", a, " appears in the file are:" ; }
$0 ~ a {  a_counter+=1  ;  }
END {  printf "%s\n", a, a_counter ; }
'  $file
```

Now it only prints the value of a, but not of a_counter. I read that `printf` is more complex and I'm probably not supposed to add multiple strings separated with "," as I could do with `print`. But I couldn't find the right way to do it? Of course I could stick with `print`, but I would like to understand what I did wrong in case of `printf`?

Comment: Good question, by the way -- thank you for taking the time and effort to isolate and clarify.

Comment: You'll be perhaps surprised that your script is not counting number of "a"s  in the file, but rather number of lines where "a" is in i.e. `grep -c a`

Comment: @karakfa: correct, thanks for pointing out this small, but important difference!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: no problem...I still get often reminded on isolating follow-up questions here on SO, but I try my best ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need one format string, like `%s`, for every variable.  So, try:

```
printf "%s %s\n", a, a_counter
```

Or:

```
printf "pattern=%s and count=%s\n", a, a_counter
```

`%s` converts any variable to a string.  If the variable is a number, other formats, like `%f` or `%e`, give you more control over how the number is converted to a string.  See `man awk` for details.

#### Examples

```
$ awk -v a="genie" -v a_counter=3 'BEGIN{ printf "%s %s\n", a, a_counter }' 
genie 3
$ awk -v a="genie" -v a_counter=3 'BEGIN{ printf "pattern=%s and count=%s\n", a, a_counter }' 
pattern=genie and count=3
$ awk -v a="genie" -v a_counter=3 'BEGIN{ printf "pattern=%s and count=%7.2f\n", a, a_counter }' 
pattern=genie and count=   3.00
$ awk -v a="genie" -v a_counter=3 'BEGIN{ printf "pattern=%s and count=%9.2e\n", a, a_counter }' 
pattern=genie and count= 3.00e+00
```

Comment: ah perfect, I did not figure that out by checking the man page...thanks for the additional examples!